# ionic build ios error ( ionic cordova build ios )

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, build

When i run "ionic cordova build ios" get error below in terminal:

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/Posify\ Kitchen.app/Posify\ Kitchen normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/YJD/Mayun_POS/posify-pos-fb-united/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Posify Kitchen.xcworkspace,-scheme,Posify Kitchen,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/YJD/Mayun_POS/posify-pos-fb-united/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/YJD/Mayun_POS/posify-pos-fb-united/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

**ionic info:**

cli packages: (/Users/YJD/Mayun_POS/posify-pos-fb-united/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.17.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.17.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v6.11.5
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. All of errors seem like "Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild......" are because of certification or Provision profile.I applied the newest provision profile and it fixed.